# CSS transition being ignored

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to add some CSS transitions to a `<div>`, but I can't seem to get it working.

Basically, I have a sidebar that slides in (using a transition itslef, which works fine), and when that happens I place a `<div>` in front of the remainder of the page.

I'm trying to use transitions because I want the aforementioned `<div>` to appear as though it is always attached to the sidebar, but it's just showing in it's final position.

Am I missing anything here?

```
#modal{
    display:    none;
    left:       0;
    opacity:    0;
    width:      100%;
}
.mobile #modal.sidebarVisible{
    background-color:   #000000;
    display:            block;
    height:             100%;
    left:               271px;
    opacity:            0.5;
    position:           absolute;
    right:              0;
    width:              calc(100% - 271px);
    z-index:            99;
    -webkit-transition: left 5s linear, width 5s linear;
    transition:         left 5s linear, width 5s linear;
}
```

*Note that I'm only using `5s` for the transition to test it's working, it'll be `0.3s` in reality.

Comment: Did you add the transition to the wrong element? You didn't post enough code, but it seems, that you added the transition to the element, how it should look like at the end, but it should be added to #modal, from where the whole transition starts.

Comment: You can't do transitions on classes that go from display: none to display: block. Because none/block is like true/false and you can't transition between those two states

Comment: I had that problem before. But I tried setting the transition with javascript and it worked... Idk

Comment: can you put it into a jsfiddle?

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex - Bingo! I replaced that with `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visible;` and the transition works.  Please post that as an answer and I'd be happy to accept.  Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I'm writing up a quick JSFiddle demo so people will have something to play with and see the difference. I'll be posting it in a few minutes =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A css transition cannot be applied to a class that is transitioning from `display: block;` to `display: none;`

Using opacity or visibility can solve this problem.

[Here's a JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/2a9eddmL/5/) The Circle is using a transition from display: block to display: none and the Square is using opacity.

Comment: Yep, I was banging my head on this for a little while. You helped.