# CSS transition is ignored due to parents display value?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

There are plenty other post regarding CSS `transition` not working due to the usage of `display` and  I do get the point. The proposed solutions are mostly the usage of `opacity` and `visibility` instead of display. Well I dind't want to do it that way even if I could as my positioning is absolute and wouldn't take any space with visibility set to 0, just like with `display: none`.

However, when I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229982/css-transition-being-ignored) thread, where the accepted answer says "...cannot be applied to a class that is transitioning from `display: block;` to `display: none;`" I thought I'm smart and applied the transition to it's child elements, meaning the parent toggles from `display: none` to `display: flex` and the children transition from `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1`. It's still not working and my assumption is that this is due to the same issue of display/transition not wanting each other, but my question is why? First I thought the display value may be inherited but it's not as the children aren't flex.

could anyone explain why it behaves like that?

To as well provide some code here is my react code using styled components for the styling.

```
const NavigationWrapper = styled.nav`
  & {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }

  @media (max-device-width: 992px) {
    & button {
      border: none;
      background-color: red;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  }

  @media (min-device-width: 993px) {
    & button {
      display: none;
    }
  }
`;

const NavList = styled.ul`
  & {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  & li {
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }

  @media (max-device-width: 992px) {
    & {
      position: absolute;
      display: ${(props) => (props.isMobileNav ? "flex" : "none")};
      flex-direction: column;
      right: 0;
      top: 100%;
      width: 100vw;
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    & li {
      opacity: ${(props) => (props.isMobileNav ? 1 : 0)};
      background-color: white;
      transition: opacity 1s ease;
    }
  }
`;
const Navigation = (props) => {
  const [isMobileNav, setIsMobileNav] = useState(false);
  return (
    <NavigationWrapper>
      <button onClick={() => setIsMobileNav(!isMobileNav)}></button>
      <NavList isMobileNav={isMobileNav}>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Profiles</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </NavList>
    </NavigationWrapper>
  );
};
```

EDIT: I tried it obviously the other way around with opacity on parent and display on children, just to try and, yes, it works. But leads to the solution I didn't want as I could set visibility to hidden or opacity to 0. I just want to know why the visibility of the parent affects the transition of the child.

Answer (score 1):

Well, an element with `display: none;` effectively gets pulled out of the flow. The code is still there, but it is treated as if it is not.

If a parent element is "removed" in this way, all children of that parent are "removed" with it, and this happens instantly. So that is why you can't do transitions of child elements, when the parent is "gone".

A solution though (if you absolutely have to use `display`), could be to use a `setTimeout()` that waits for the duration of the transition, before setting `display: none;` (the other way, setting `display: flex;` should work with transitions on child elements just fine).

Something like this, although this simple example poses issues regarding unmounting, and you should quard it with a cancel mechanism, that can interrupt the timeout when unmounting the component:

```js
<button
  onClick={() => {
    // Delayed
    if (isMobileNav) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsMobileNav(false);
      }, 1000);
      return;
    }
    // Instant
    setIsMobileNav(true);
  }}
>
</button>
```

Comment: Yes, makes sense for display: none but not the other way round, when it is pushed back into the flow I‘d expect that the transition happens right after the parent is shown. But it‘s not.

Comment: I think there is something about transition not being able to "re-trigger". Try playing with the `animation` property instead (`@keyframes`).
But can I ask, why you can't/won't use "the other solution" when it works?

Comment: I did in the meantime. I used opacity 0 on parent together with display none on direct children, which works as the parent collapses (as long as no width or height is set) automatically for the reason that it's children don't need space. 
However, I didn't want to use it as I've been reading through SO and some recommend it, others warn for uncertain behaviour. This makes it not a totally good practice I'd like to avoid. 

In addition I'm just curious. I expected the swap from 'none' to 'flex' immediately and then the transition. Understanding why things are is important for me.